# How to set AppClip invocation for URL with QueryParam?

Tags: swift, android-instant-apps, apple-appclips

I am trying to set the AppClip invocation for my App which is already released on app store.
I need an url such that it provides me a jobId e.g.: https://example.com/task?jobId=00001.

My use case is that I send the sms with the url https://example.com/task?jobId=00001 to the user, the user clicks on the url and the app gets started. Then for the other user I send the next url with corresponding *jobId*.

I did setup the AASA file for my domain (contains the JSON with "applinks" and "appclip" objects) which is valid, also the ***Domain status*** is valid on App Store Connect. There is a default experience set with title, subtitle, image and action. I also configured an advance experience for the url *https://example.com/task*.

However, my app clip doesn't get invoked if I access the url from either sms text or safari. :(

I do not have a web page for https://example.com/task therefore I haven't set up the meta data for this.

Is it possible to invoke the AppClip this way? It is really important for me that the URL is dynamic and I pass that *jobId* every time for each individual booking.

There s no much documentation and I already read at least twice Apple documentation about AppClip.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:

> I do not have a web page for https://example.com/task therefore I haven't set up the meta data for this.

The answer to this:

> Is it possible to invoke the AppClip this way?

Is no. Sorry, you need to own the domain you're working with, or at the very least have means to access its CNAME config (thus, be able to induce the owner of that domain to change the CNAME configs to what you want it to be, similar to what branch.io and AppsFlyer does with its users/clients).